# Android Error at at com.example.appname.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:21)

Tags: java, android, xml, eclipse, mobile-application

I'm trying to create an app as a YouTube player. It launches successfully, but whenever I try to open my app. App is stopping in emulator. I couldn't figure out my problem. Appreciate your bits of help.

***MainAcivity.java***

```
package com.example.youtubeplayer;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.os.Bundle;
import androidx.annotation.Nullable;
import android.widget.Toast;
import com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubeInitializationResult;
import com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubePlayer;
import com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubePlayerView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

String api_key = "AIzaSyDoCqWQdWVzhVX1BgHFzV1Ara3iH-vMpZk";

@Override
protected void
onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    // Get reference to the view of Video player
    YouTubePlayerView ytPlayer = findViewById(R.id.ytPlayer);

    ytPlayer.initialize(
            api_key,
            new YouTubePlayer.OnInitializedListener() {
                // Implement two methods by clicking on red
                // error bulb inside onInitializationSuccess
                // method add the video link or the playlist
                // link that you want to play In here we
                // also handle the play and pause
                // functionality
                @Override
                public void onInitializationSuccess(
                        YouTubePlayer.Provider provider,
                        YouTubePlayer youTubePlayer, boolean b)
                {
                    youTubePlayer.loadVideo("gEPIyWlAwIw");
                    youTubePlayer.play();
                }

                // Inside onInitializationFailure
                // implement the failure functionality
                // Here we will show toast
                @Override
                public void onInitializationFailure(YouTubePlayer.Provider provider,
                                                    YouTubeInitializationResult
                                                            youTubeInitializationResult)
                {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Video player Failed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            });
   }
}
```

***AndroidManifest.xml***

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/Theme.YouTubePlayer">
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:exported="true">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>

</manifest>
```

***activity_main.xml***

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubePlayerView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/ytPlayer"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

**Logcat**

```
2022-01-19 12:11:16.396 8958-8958/? I/e.youtubeplaye: Not late-enabling -Xcheck:jni (already on)
2022-01-19 12:11:16.409 8958-8958/? E/e.youtubeplaye: Unknown bits set in runtime_flags: 0x8000
2022-01-19 12:11:16.409 8958-8958/? W/e.youtubeplaye: Unexpected CPU variant for X86 using defaults: x86
2022-01-19 12:11:16.656 8958-8991/com.example.youtubeplayer D/libEGL: Emulator has host GPU support, qemu.gles is set to 1.
2022-01-19 12:11:16.656 8958-8991/com.example.youtubeplayer W/libc: Unable to set property "qemu.gles" to "1": connection failed; errno=13 (Permission denied)
2022-01-19 12:11:16.650 8958-8958/com.example.youtubeplayer W/RenderThread: type=1400 audit(0.0:46): avc: denied { write } for name="property_service" dev="tmpfs" ino=267 scontext=u:r:untrusted_app:s0:c133,c256,c512,c768 tcontext=u:object_r:property_socket:s0 tclass=sock_file permissive=0 app=com.example.youtubeplayer
2022-01-19 12:11:16.669 8958-8991/com.example.youtubeplayer D/libEGL: loaded /vendor/lib/egl/libEGL_emulation.so
2022-01-19 12:11:16.672 8958-8991/com.example.youtubeplayer D/libEGL: loaded /vendor/lib/egl/libGLESv1_CM_emulation.so
2022-01-19 12:11:16.675 8958-8991/com.example.youtubeplayer D/libEGL: loaded /vendor/lib/egl/libGLESv2_emulation.so
2022-01-19 12:11:16.834 8958-8958/com.example.youtubeplayer W/e.youtubeplaye: Accessing hidden method Landroid/view/View;->computeFitSystemWindows(Landroid/graphics/Rect;Landroid/graphics/Rect;)Z (greylist, reflection, allowed)
2022-01-19 12:11:16.835 8958-8958/com.example.youtubeplayer W/e.youtubeplaye: Accessing hidden method Landroid/view/ViewGroup;->makeOptionalFitsSystemWindows()V (greylist, reflection, allowed)
2022-01-19 12:11:16.853 8958-8958/com.example.youtubeplayer D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
2022-01-19 12:11:16.854 8958-8958/com.example.youtubeplayer E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.youtubeplayer, PID: 8958
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.youtubeplayer/com.example.youtubeplayer.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #13 in com.example.youtubeplayer:layout/activity_main: Binary XML file line #13 in com.example.youtubeplayer:layout/activity_main: Error inflating class com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubePlayerView
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3270)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3409)
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:83)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2016)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7356)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:492)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:930)
     Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #13 in com.example.youtubeplayer:layout/activity_main: Binary XML file line #13 in com.example.youtubeplayer:layout/activity_main: Error inflating class com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubePlayerView
     Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #13 in com.example.youtubeplayer:layout/activity_main: Error inflating class com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubePlayerView
     Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:343)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:854)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:1006)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:961)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:1123)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:1084)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:682)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:534)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:481)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:706)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:195)
        at com.example.youtubeplayer.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:21)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7802)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7791)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1299)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3245)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3409)
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:83)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2016)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7356)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:492)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:930)
     Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: A YouTubePlayerView can only be created with an Activity  which extends YouTubeBaseActivity as its context.
2022-01-19 12:11:16.854 8958-8958/com.example.youtubeplayer E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubePlayerView.<init>(Unknown Source:19)
        at com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubePlayerView.<init>(Unknown Source:1)
            ... 28 more
```

Answer (score 0):

you have clear hint in your stacktrace (4th line from bottom of posted lines)

> A YouTubePlayerView can only be created with an Activity  which extends YouTubeBaseActivity as its context.

so exchange this line

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
```

to this

```
public class MainActivity extends YouTubeBaseActivity {
```

Comment: Thank you so much, it's working now.

Comment: consider upvoting/accepting answer if helpful, thats how this site works :) good luck!